# CSS property reference with text node content?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a user style hack on a internal tool and i would like to keep it CSS only (so i can use the stylish extension i already use on every browser instead of adding grease monkey style extensions)

the system has the following html:

```
<a href="...">
    <span>
        <img src="...">
    </span>
    username
</a>
```

the image is a place holder as the system is not integrated with anything.

i can get user avatars in the company with a url like `http://company.com/avatars/<username>.png`

and CSS allows me to do things like

```
/* show link destination after the A tag contents */
a:after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ")";
}
```

My plan is to add user-CSS to hide the useless image, and append a background to the `A` tag showing the company avatar for that user. There is nothing on the `A` tag properties that can help me. The only hint is at the A tag text node direct and last child.

is there any way to do that with CSS only?

since this is a user-style hack for a internal tool, the more bleeding edge tech the better. no need to support all browsers, care about perf, etc.

Comment: Selecting by text is not supported by css3, Your best bet is to find any identifier on the `href` attr, but you seem to have tried this already.  An a side note; there was a proposal for `:contains()` but it got dropped, [see 6.6.6](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#content-selectors). And while there is no proof Satan was involved in its removal, it hasn't been disproven either. I'm monitoring this question in case you find a way to the light and don't have to sell your soul to the evils of JavaScript. 
-amen

Comment: thanks for the support and great info @lars i almost got it working on another system that have username in a attribute but then i couldn't create the string for the background image because only `content` allows string concatenation. `background-image` do not...  i think this whole question is moot because of that, but leaving open for now

Comment: Depending on how many usernames there actually are, you could give each username its own cssrule. 

If the names are added/changed to often, you might want to look at [js-injector](https://github.com/shahverdy/JS-Injector)

Comment: @js-injector that is the only answer i am afraid. and unfortunately, it is not even close to an option for me. oh well. js it is. silly css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is impossible.

there is no way to concatenate the usernames into the image. `background` attributes do not accept string concatenation like `content`. one would think the same rules for string values would apply to all css properties, well, `content` seems to be special.

as pointed on comments, it would be possible to have the full `background` url on the css rule and match based on the username, but then you would have to add one rule per username you want to match. not really an option over 1k records.